# Havok - Can you change color of objects during runtime?

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-physics, mesh, havok

To anybody who has some experience with the Havok Physics Engine:

Is there a way to change the color of meshes/objects during runtime? I am working with the demo framework and I want to change the color of all the meshes/objects (in a demo) that are in-motion (`velocity > 0`). Its my first time using Havok. Can't find anything about it in the documentation I have.

Thanks!

On a sidenote: I have noticed that there are very little questions about Havok on stackoverflow and when I search questions about Havok online I can't seem to find anything. Where do all the Havok devs go to chat? They have a forum or something?

Comment: They migrated to the [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @SmitYcyken There are even fewer questions regarding Havok on there. How is it possible that there are so few discussions about Havok on the internet? Its a pretty well known Physics engine. Plenty of peoplpe use it...

Comment: What about `HK_SET_OBJECT_COLOR`? it was the first link after googling your question [Phantom Triggers](http://brandondgameengines.blogspot.ru/2013/11/phantom-triggersevents-with-havok.html)

Comment: Havok is mostly popular with larger teams that are capable of paying for support. It hasn't been popular among indie and small-time developers that often frequent SO and SE sites. You will find that these sites best cater to open-source software with large communities, and Havok simply isn't that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

The solution using HVD - Havok Visual Debugger:

```
// Needed for calling color change macro
#include <common\visualize\hkdebugdisplay.h>

// You'll of course need any other headers for any other physics stuff 
// you're doing in your file

void SetColorForPhysicsDebugger( unsigned int Red, unsigned int Green,
                                 unsigned int Blue, unsigned int Alpha, 
                                 const hkpCollidable* pCollidable )
{
    // Havok takes an unsigned int (32-bit), allowing 8-bits for 
    // each channel (alpha, red, green, and blue, in that
    // order).

    // Because we only need 8-bits from each of the 32-bit ints 
    // passed into this function, we'll mask the first 24-bits.
    Red &= 0x000000FF;
    Green &= 0x000000FF;
    Blue &= 0x000000FF;
    Alpha &= 0x000000FF;

    // Now we pack the four channels into a single int
    const uint32_t color = (Alpha << 24) | (Red << 16) | (Green << 8) | Blue;

    // We use the macro provided by Havok
    HK_SET_OBJECT_COLOR( reinterpret_cast<hkulong>( pCollidable ), color );
}
```

For more information about HVD: [HVD and camera](http://nic-gamedev.blogspot.ru/2011/11/havok-connecting-your-in-game-camera-to.html) ,[Setting mesh color](http://nic-gamedev.blogspot.ru/2011/11/havok-setting-mesh-color-in-visual.html)

Comment: I have seen that blog post but that seems to work only for Havok's Visual Debugger and not during actual running demos. I want to be able to set the color while running the actual demo and not the visual debugger of the demo.